# Blob Cache and List Item Attachments?

Tags: 2010, attachments, caching, blob-cache

If I use the Blob Cache, are List Item **attachments** cached in it?  Are there any special considerations for using the Blob Cache with list item attachments?

Answer (score 1):

At the point in the API where the blob caching mechanism is invoked, a list item attachment looks no different than a library item (...it's a BLOB read).  They are absolutely included in the BLOB cache and do not require any special consideration.

Comment: Just be sure that the file extensions of the items you are expecting to be cached are included in the Blob Cache setting in the web.config

Comment: Yup, extensions are there.  I thought this would be the case, but was traversing the file system on the WFE and wasn't seeing any of the things I was expecting to see...